# MacBook Pro taking 30 seconds at loading screen (before login screen)

Tags: macbook-pro

I've noticed that lately my MacBook has taken around 30 seconds to start up (time it takes to get to login screen). It seems to take away during the loading bar screen. It used to only take 5-ish seconds.

I have an Early 2015 MacBook Pro. I think this issue started occurring when I reset my SMC a few weeks ago. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does anything change if you do a Safe Boot? (EG hold shift at startup until you see the Apple logo)

Comment: Was typing the same thing @SteveChambers said.  Your SMC is related to power, not what gets loaded during boot, so that's very unlikely to be the issue.  If [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) doesn't yield anything try booting from a USB (USB 3 preferably) flash drive (32GB is sufficient) with a clean version of macOS installed to it.  If it's more "normal" there, you might consider a fresh install.  But test this way first before wiping your drive.

Comment: @SteveChambers Not sure what I was supposed to observe in Safe Boot. What changes should I be looking for? I was on the Apple Logo for about 2-3 minutes before it went to the log in screen, at which point, I restarted my computer in normal mode and it still took 30 seconds ish to start up.

Comment: @Allan What do you mean by "if Safe Mode *doesn't yield anything*?" What should I be looking for in Safe Mode? I booted into Safe Mode just now. It took about 2-3 minutes to get to the log in screen, at which point, I restarted and booted back up in normal made but had the same issue.

Comment: If booting in Safe Mode you see that response times are more normal, then it's something to do with macOS and what's being loaded during boot.  If the problem persists, there's a bigger issue - it may be something "deeper" in the OS (possibly corruption) or it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: @Allan Ah I see, but I don't think I know what "normal" is for Safe Mode. Should safe mode's normal be what I used to observe in normal startup in the past (i.e., a few seconds)? 


I don't think it's a hardware issue. I actually had my battery replaced 3 weeks ago (this issue started before the battery replacement), and at that time no hardware issues were found besides the battery.

Comment: It's been a while since I had a fusion drive in my iMac, but login was usually no more than 10 seconds or so.  It wasn't 2-3 mins.  Sometimes it was more if things had to be cleaned up (like if recovering from a crash).  Before ruling things out (like hardware), let's start testing and see where it takes us.

Comment: @user5965026 on a fairly basic level Safe Boot should be a bit faster because it is not loading any 3rd party software and only a subset of the Apple software that is necessary for basic functionality. Note that Safe Boot often takes longer because of the disk checking and other maintenance duties macOS does. So you may need to try it a few times and note if the times you noticed being loooooonger are (even a little bit) shorter. Another thing might be to use a "cleaning" tool like Onyx that removes caches, does scheduled maintenance, etc.